# SQLite3 - select date range not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

yet anotherone that gives me grief.

In a SQLite3 DB Select I query for a date range specified in (NSDate *)fromDate to (NSDate *)toDate

```
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.key = B.key AND A.date between ? and ?";
```

After opening the DB I run the query in Objective-C as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *tmpDatFmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[tmpDatFmt setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"From %s to %s;", [[tmpDatFmt stringFromDate:fromDate] UTF8String], [[tmpDatFmt stringFromDate:toDate] UTF8String]);

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[tmpDatFmt stringFromDate:fromDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);  // first '?'
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[tmpDatFmt stringFromDate:toDate]   UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);  // second '?'

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSLog(@"Success");}
```

In the database I have several records that match the date range:

```
12-04-2010 = in seconds 1271059200
13-04-2010 = in seconds 1271145600
13-04-2010 = in seconds 1271152800
14-04-2010 = in seconds 1271267100
```

When I run it the first NSLog shows

```
From 2010-04-01 to 2010-04-30
```

my problem is the records are not selected (no "Success" shows in the log) and I don't understand why.

earlier I had miscalculated the dates 2 days later as

```
14-04-2010 = in seconds 1271232000
15-04-2010 = in seconds 1271318400
15-04-2010 = in seconds 1271325600
16-04-2010 = in seconds 1271439936
```

These dates worked fine (4 x "Success in the log). I am puzzled ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no date type (though it has good date functions). Your comparisons are done on strings, To make them work correctly you should change your format to yyyyMMdd or yyyy-MM-dd so they sort in date order.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for this hint. I think I'll redefine the column to a double in sqlite3 and use sqlite_bind_double. Hope that'll work, too.
Cheers

Comment: And - whilst reducing the field to an int (fully sufficient) it did work ... :)

Answer (score 1):

you might also try a different more natural way (natural to sqlite):

```
select date(..date.fld...,'start of year') = '2011-01-01' ; 
  //any 2011 date will get selected
select date(..date.fld...,'start of year') >= '2011-01-01'; 
  // 2011, 2012 etc
```

to see other date functions check this link: [www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.htm](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.htm)

Actually the `date.fld` seems to be any field that has date data in it whether string, utf, integer, whatever but implementations may vary.

I use sqlite3 with python 2.6 and get consistent results...